# Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8mb4 character string

Tags: mysql

I have created a table from a csv file using built in mysql workbench wizard.
The structure was created and also 3 test rows were imported into the table.
Now I wanted to use the very same csv which i used to create the table in the first place and load the same 3 rows once again but using the LOAD DATA INFILE command.
I am getting error code: 1300. The string field contains german ü characters which I assume are the problem but why ? The column already contains string values with those characters.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8q8p.png)

Comment: [LOAD DATA statement # Input File Character Set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-character-set)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - provide CREATE TABLE for destination table, CSV file body and your server charset/collation settings. Also specify precise MySQL version. And none screenshots - properly formatted text only.

Comment: Did you double check that your input CSV file is UTF8?